# Is there a way to see the last send value in sendable data extensions in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, appexchange

Is there a way in SFMC to know what is the last send value for the sendable Data Extensions? We want to clean up unused or old legacy sendable DEs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There no way to automate to get the history on which data extension you have used to send an email.

But,you can get it via UI (its a manual process), if you go to `Email Studio > Email > Tracking > Sends > Click on the email name > You can see which is the source it is used to send.`

Note, you can only able to see upto last 6 months.

If you are doing the same activity in future then the below approach will definitely help.

You can create a new master DE which will store the values of which is the source from which the email has sent from and when it has been added into master DE.

Add the below snippet to all the emails.

```
%%[
  SET @source = _DataSourceName
  InsertDE("Data extension Name", "colNameForSource", @source,"createddate",NOW())
]%%
```

You can also leverage any other marketing cloud personalizzation string like Job ID, Batch ID , List ID etc.. from the below reference.

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

Post some time like 6 months or so, you check and remove the un-wanted DE's.

Let me know if this helps.